# Probability of a Survey

Tags: probability

> Among the participants in a survey,
>
> - $30\%$ live in the suburbs
> - $50\%$ are over $40$ years old
>
> One participant is selected at random. The sharpest bound that can be justified based on the information given on the chance that the participant lives in the suburbs and is over $40$ years old is?

How would you approach such a probability?

(Participants lives in Suburbs and Over 40 Years old)=Multiple Rule;

$P($Participant Suburbs$) \cdot P($Over 40 Years Old$) =
(0.30 \cdot 0.50)=0.15=$ at the most $15\%$?

Answer (score 2):

It is **conceivable**  that nobody in the suburbs is over $40$. It is conceivable that everybody in the suburbs is over $40$.  So the sharpest **certain** estimate is that the percentage in the suburbs and over $40$  is between $0$ and $30$ percent.

**Remark:** The truth for sure lies between $0$ and $30$. Multiplying $0.3$ by $0.5$ as in your proposal assumes *independence* of the events "lives in the suburbs" and "is over $40$." These events are undoubtedly not independent.

Answer (score 2):

Think about this: isn't it possible that no one over 40 lives in the suburbs? Isn't it possible that everyone in the suburbs is over 40?